# Bloquear login através de CURL PHP

Tags: php, libcurl

Tenho um formulário de login que envia dados via post e gostaria de bloquear o login via curl.
Isso é possível?

Comment: Minha resposta deu certo pra você?

Comment: Deu sim mano valeu :D, tbm estou usando http_reference.

Comment: O que resolve de uma forma realmente decente é Recaptcha. De resto tudo é possível simular via CURL. O recaptcha tb pode ser resolvido por robo, mas é bem mais dificil.

Comment: E cuidado com filtro pelo referrer. Não é tão eficiente assim fazer isso, o cara pode ter fechado o navegador e reaberto carregando a pagina q estava aberta. Ou simplesmente alguem pode ter enviado o link pra ele por email ou por algum aplicativo de mensagem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

É possível se você utilizar uma boa de engenharia para `Cross-Site Request Forgery (CSRF) Prevention`.

Basicamente, seu formulário terá um campo onde você armazena um `token` o qual possui um tempo de vida e é validado na url que recebe o formulário. O cUrl não saberá preencher o valor deste campo que é dinâmico e gerado durante a rendenização do `<form`

Exemplo extremamente simples:

```
<?php

$token = md5(uniqid(rand(), TRUE));
$_SESSION['token'] = $token;


?>
<form action="controller.php" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="token" value="<?php echo $token; ?>" />
<input type="submit/>
</form>
```

Em controller.php:

```
<?php 
if ($_POST['token'] == $_SESSION['token']){
    /* Valid Token */
}
```

Comment: Mas na teoria se ele fizer uma acesso a página do form primeiro, e pegar esse token, ele conseguiria realizar o login sem problemas ?

Comment: Sim, se mantiver a mesma sessão. Deste modo, o script precisa ser mais sofisticado. O próximo passo de segurança é utilizar Teclado Virtual ou Captcha